# Parse.com Query Not Loading

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, parse-platform

I'm creating an app with displays parse data in a table view. I downloaded a template from https://github.com/Bizzi-Body/HowToDisplayImagesInTableViewFromParse it all worked fine when I ran it but when I put my Parse app id in and Client id it just shows a loading screen (see  Screenshot)

So I thought it might be a problem with the app template so downloaded a different one and edited it, but the same problem happen, so I'm think its something wrong with my parse account settings.

[image: screenshot]

```swift
import UIKit

class TableViewController: PFQueryTableViewController {

    // Initialise the PFQueryTable tableview
    override init!(style: UITableViewStyle, className: String!) {
        super.init(style: style, className: className)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        // Configure the PFQueryTableView
        self.parseClassName = "Photo"
        self.textKey = "updatedAt"
        self.pullToRefreshEnabled = true
        self.paginationEnabled = false
    }

    // Define the query that will provide the data for the table view
    override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery! {
        var query = PFQuery(className: "Photo")
        query.orderByAscending("updatedAt")
        return query
    }

    //override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject) -> PFTableViewCell {

        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as CustomCell!
        if cell == nil {
            cell = CustomCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        }

        // Extract values from the PFObject to display in the table cell
        cell.username.text = object["user"] as String!
        cell.itemdetail.text = object["description"] as String!
        cell.price.text = object["Price"] as String!

        var thumbnail = object["Image"] as PFFile
        var initialThumbnail = UIImage(named: "question")
        cell.productimage.image = initialThumbnail
        cell.productimage.file = thumbnail
        cell.productimage.loadInBackground()


        return cell
    }


}
```

Comment: Hey George.  I can not think of anything off the top of my head as to why this might happen - and I've not had this myself before.  (But that doesn't help you - and problems like this are soon annoying)  Question - do you get any messages in the Xcode debug window?  If NOT then that suggests that your keys are correct - Parse will complain if anything is wrong there.

Comment: There is a switch in your parse app settings where you can enable/disable users to create classes - default setting is enabled.  (Good practice is actually to have this disabled and set to "no")  Please set this to "no" and attempt to run the app again - if there is any problem with you class names you will get a message in your debug window - this might help.  Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If you enabled Parse LocalDatastore a quite similar issue is here:

https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseUI-iOS/issues/26

So try to disable LocalDatastore or update ParseSDK

Comment: I couldn't find any thing to do with localdatastore but i updated the parse sdk but it didn't work, same error happening

Comment: I just let the app load after about 6 minutes the loading sign changes to just a white screen with no content in it but i can still swipe up to refresh

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the Custom Cell class name does not match the Custom Cell Class detailed in the story board.

If your custom cell class is called "CustomCell" (i.e. - in "CustomCell.swift") you need to make sure that in the story board the custom class setting for the prototype cell is also "CustomCell".

Maybe this changed when you created your one custom class/cell